# N-Knights - JAVA

Tags: java

I tried to write N-Knight's problem, but failed.
Could you guide me on this, please go through my below coding(8-by-8 two-dimensional array), 
I am not sure whether my coding is matching to  - The Knight can move in the shape of the letter, 'L', over two in one direction and then over one in a perpendicular direction.
And, how to - If the Knight rests at the square marked X ?

```
package knightstour;
import java.util.*;

public class KnightsTour 
{
    private static int board[][] = new int[8][8];
    private static int stepCounter = 1;

    public KnightsTour() {
        initBoard(board);
        tour(0,0);
        printSol(board);
    }

    public static void printSol(int[][] a) {
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < a[i].length; j++) {
                if(a[i][j]>9) {
                    System.out.print(a[i][j] + "  ");
                } else {
                    System.out.print(a[i][j] + "   ");
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    public static void initBoard(int[][] a) {
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) 
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < a[i].length; j++) 
            {
                a[i][j] = -1;
            }
        }
    }

    public void tour(int x, int y) {
        if (((x < 0) || (x >= 8) || (y < 0) || (y >= 8)) || (board[x][y] != -1)) {
            return;
        }
        else {
            board[x][y] = stepCounter++;
            tour(x+2, y+1);
            tour(x+1, y-2);
            tour(x+1, y+2);
            tour(x-1, y+2);
            tour(x-2, y-1);
            tour(x-2, y+1);
            tour(x-1, y-2);
            tour(x+2, y-1);  
        }
    }

    public boolean spaceAvailable(int X, int Y) {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new KnightsTour();
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're question is (I have no clue what the N-Knights problem is). Can you describe what you're trying to do and what the N-Knights problem is? And then can you describe instead what your code is doing. It would help us answer if we knew what you wanted to do and what instead was happening (how is what your code is doing different from what you want it to do)

Comment: My understanding is that the N knights problem is to find a way to place N knights on a chessboard, so that no knight is attacking any other knight.  A knight's tour is a path in which a single knight visits every square on the board.  These two concepts are entirely unrelated, so it doesn't make sense to me to have code that talks about knight's tours in a solution to the N knights problem.

Comment: Hi Dawood, I am new in Java. I try to write my coding to fulfil the below requirements, but failed. - The Knights must visits the maximum number of board positions without attacking each other. The Knight can move in the shape of the letter, 'L', over two in one direction and then over one in a perpendicular direction. 
If the Knight rests at the square marked X.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your code is starting at 0,0 and trying to see the minimum number of steps it takes to visit every other space in your board while only moving like a Knight does in Chess then your code actually looks fine logic-wise.

Your issue seems to be `board[x][y] = stepCounter++;`

`stepCounter++` is actually a shortcut for writing `stepCounter = stepCounter + 1`. So that doesn't really make any sense.. `stepCounter++` isn't an assignable value, its a command to do something.

It would be like writing `board[x][y] = (stepCounter = stepCounter + 1);`

Try executing that command first, THEN assigning the value.

```
public void tour(int x, int y)  {
    if (((x < 0) || (x >= 8) || (y < 0) || (y >= 8)) || (board[x][y] != -1)) {
        return;
    } else {
        stepCounter++;
        board[x][y] = stepCounter;
        tour(x+2, y+1);
        tour(x+1, y-2);
        tour(x+1, y+2);
        tour(x-1, y+2);
        tour(x-2, y-1);
        tour(x-2, y+1);
        tour(x-1, y-2);
        tour(x+2, y-1);  
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Gadu, Could you help me on below ?

Comment: The N-Knight's problem must attempts to move around the chess board so that the Knights must visits the maximum number of board positions without attacking each other. The Knight can move in the shape of the letter, 'L', over two in one direction and then over one in a perpendicular direction. 
And if the Knight rests at the square marked X.

Comment: Can you use my coding to further develop or ? Thanks.